# How to access variable from other function in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am working on one project and wanted to implement it in OOP. So for that I have craeted one class `Person` having 2 different methods `funcA` which returns fullname and `funcB` which takes varible from `funcA` and return age.

Now my question is how can i use `var2` from function `funcA` into the `funcB`.

```
class Person:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def funcA(self):
        var1 = self.name + "Satav"
        var2 = 22

        return(var1)
    
    def funcB(self):
        return("my age is " + var2)

dc = Person("Mayur")

#first wanted to run funcA
fullname = dc.funcA()
print(fullname)

#then wanted to run funcB
age = funcB()
print(age)
```

I tried many available solution but got confused. Please apologies for this silly question

*I am working on one complex project and because of that it not possible to add entire code here. and that's why i use this dummy scenario*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here try this code-

```
class Person:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.var1 = ''
        self.var2 = 0

    def funcA(self):
        self.var1 = self.name + " Satav"
        self.var2 = 22

        return(self.var1)
    
    def funcB(self):
        return(f"my age is {self.var2}")

dc = Person("Mayur")

#first wanted to run funcA
fullname = dc.funcA()
print(fullname)

#then wanted to run funcB
age = dc.funcB()
print(age)
```

First of all i have defined the variables in the init menthod so they can be accessed.
And second of all i used f-string to format 'funtB'.
Last of all i fixed some errors in your code.
Cheers!

I Hope the following code helps you further

```
I have defined the funcB outside of the class. Two values cannot be returned to functA so i have printed them out
def funcB(value):
    print(f"my age is {value}")

class Person:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.var1 = ''
        self.var2 = 0

    def funcA(self):
        fullname = self.name + " Satav"

        print(fullname)

        funcB(self.var2)

dc = Person("Mayur")

#first wanted to run funcA
fullname = dc.funcA()
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the edit is to change `funcB` to:

```
def funcB(self):
    A_VAR = self.funcA
    return "my age is " + A_VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to make `var2` be `age` and be one of the attributes of the class, that way you could access it in any method that has `self` in it.

Example:

```
class Person:
    
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

        
    def funcA(self):
        var1 = self.name + "Satav"
        #since you were only returning var1, var2 was doing nothing here

        return(var1)
    
    def funcB(self):
        return("my age is " + self.age)

dc = Person("Mayur", 22)

#first wanted to run funcA
fullname = dc.funcA()
print(fullname)

#then wanted to run funcB
age = funcB()
print(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

After `return(var1)` in `funcA()`, put `global var2`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    
def funcA(self):
    var1 = self.name + "Satav"
    self.var2 = 22

    return(var1)

def funcB(self):
    return("my age is " + str(self.var2))

dc = Person("Mayur")

#first wanted to run funcA
fullname = dc.funcA()
print(fullname)

#then wanted to run funcB
age = dc.funcB()
print(age)
```

It would be best to set var2 as a local variable of the class instead of one function, as you are calling var2 in another function in another scope. But this here can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows

```
def Person(name, age=None):
    print('name: {}'.format(name))
    if(age is not None):
        print('age: {}'.format(age))
    else:
        print('age: not informed')
```

And call the function this way

```
Person('Mayur', 22)
```

The result

```
name: Mayur                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
age: 22
```

If you call the aged function, this way

```
Person('Joe')
```

As defined in the function if you do not enter the age, the function returns

```
name: Joe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
age: not informed
```